# Why do we use $...$ with irrational numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion, pattern-recognition, pattern-matching

That $...$ in title means the $...$ used at the end of example in question body. So my question is you must have numbers/patterns like

$$ W={1,2,3 ...} $$

Here $ .. $ makes sense. Also

$$ \frac{1}{3}=0.33... $$

Here also $...$ makes sense. However when we take an irrational numbers we write it as

$ 1.43857358357385... $

Now if we asked to find the fifth term of first $2$ examples we can easily tell this that is why we use point. However we don't know the next digit which will we used. Then why do we use $...$?

**Background**- Today I was learning set theory and there $...$ came which made me think and ask this question. I have tried fully to add context but sorry if it lacks context.

Comment: I do not know which answer you expect. I do not have an answer, but it should be clear that this indicates that the digits are "going on" and there are infinite many. Also theoretically it is possible to approximate every irrational up to a sufficient point. When you want to know the n-th digit of $\pi$, then you can compute it. How difficult this is, is an other question.

Comment: Decimal expansion is just one way of expressing the value of a number - sometimes it is the most convenient. Other times numbers arise as the ratios of lengths (eg $\pi$) or the roots of equations or continued fractions or sums of convergent series - the form in which a number is expressed is not the same as the number itself, and can be chosen for convenience.

Comment: The ellipsis just signifies continuation in this case. It is not indicating a pattern.

Comment: @Cornman definitely I can calculate value of $\pi$ because it is defined irrational number  however if I take the example 3 of my question then how can you predict the $n$th digit. And if we can't predict then why the decimal

Comment: You said "why do we use...?", why do we use what??

Comment: That $...$ means the $...$ used at the end of example in title. I have edited the q now

Comment: The question is simple. "$...$" refers to simply something that "continues on." It doesn't need a pattern. Sometimes, a pattern is convenient, but not necessary to use this notation.

Comment: @MarkBennet  https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/write-5-irrational-numbers-between-sqrt3-and-sqrt5/ Like you can read here there is $...$ used at end of irrational number but isn't $..$ used when there is a pattern?

Comment: I do not know how to predict the n-th digit of your sequence of decimial points, because we need a specific definition of how your number is constructed. Then we have a way to approximate it. For example your number could be the solution to a certain equation, which can be approximated. $\pi$ is clearly defined, and there are algorithms which converge very fast. $\sqrt{2}$ is one solution to $x^2-2=0$ and can be approximated from this. But what is your number?

Comment: It's notation.  And it's sloppily informal.  "..." means "and so on indefinitely".   And what exactly that means depends entirely on context and *frequently* (purist would say *always*) is ambiguous and unclear.  $0.3333....$ it is by our organic human gestalt brains obvious we must mean that the number is $3$ forever.  And if we write $1,2, 4,8,.... $ it's obvious we must mean that $n$th term is $2^{n-1}$.  And if we have $1.43857358357385...$ because we can't obvious see an intended pattern we just assume this indicates a non terminating decimal with no pattern.

Comment: Maybe OP is mixing up $\ 0.333\ldots\ $ with $\ \frac{1}{3} = 0.\overset{.}{3}\ $?

Comment: "if I take the example 3 of my question then how can you predict the nth digit" You can't.  Why would you think you could?  "And if we can't predict then why the decimal" What other options do you have?  It means "Well, up to the 14th decimal place it is such but after that I have no idea but 14 decimal places is $10^{11}$ times good enough for government work so that's as good as I'm willing to get".

Comment: This - https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node12.html - on computing the digits of $\pi$ notes a method for computing the $N^{th}$ hexadecimal digit of $\pi$ without computing the previous digits.

Comment: I think this question is a good one.  There are well-accepted contexts where we would never write (or accept the use of) $\ldots$ or $\ddots$ without a self-evident pattern.  The OP’s confusion (“why not in this case”?) is a pretty natural one.

Comment: Rational numbers can, in principle , always be written in bar notation, this is not the case for irrational numbers : every expansion (not only in base $10$ , in every integer base $b\ge 2$) is non-terminating and without a period that repeats forever. The only way to indicate this is "$\cdots$"

Comment: @Cornman - It is absolutely not the case that, for any real number, there is an algorithm to compute the number up to arbitrary precision. That's what it means for a real to be computable, and there are many non-computable reals.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Correct, in fact, the computable numbers have density $0$.

Comment: @Peter Your use of "density" here is unfamiliar to me.  The computable numbers are dense (topologically) in the reals.  However, the computable numbers are a countable set, and therefore have (Lebesgue) measure zero.  Is this what you mean by "density"?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, I used perhaps an unlucky terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the construct $\dots$ is used to mark an intentional omission, it is called an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). This usage is not limited or particular to mathematics.

It does not necessarily indicate that we know enough to fill in the blank.

There can by different reasons to omit something. One reason is that it is more or less redundant, this is the usage you have in mind. Others are that it is not very relevant to give all the details or that it is impossible to include everything.

The usage in the examples you mention are along the lines of these later cases. On the one hand we cannot possibly give all the decimal digits on the other hand to know the first few might be sufficient for our use-case.

Comment: That wikipedia link and "It does not necessarily indicate that we know enough to fill in the blank" helped me the most. Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

$a = 1.23 \ldots $ is just a shorthand for $0 \leq a - 1.23 \leq 0.01$

Comment: That's absolutely right.

Comment: (+1), but technically shouldn't it be $0 \le a - 1.23 \color{red}{\le}0.01$ because it might be that $a=1.239999\dots$, in which case $a=1.24$?

Comment: @Joe I guess you are right, or it depends on the convention... Let me rewrite it as you say, to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Sasha: Thanks. Ironically, when I wrote $a=1.239999\dots$, that *was* an instance in which the ellipsis indicated a repeating pattern.